# How to add circular chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, charts, circular-dependency

I want this image in my flutter app.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this plugin   [pie_chart: ^5.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart/install)

```
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

Map<String, double> dataMap = {
    "Flutter": 5,
    "React": 3,
    "Xamarin": 2,
    "Ionic": 2,
  };

PieChart(
      dataMap: dataMap,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      chartLegendSpacing: 32,
      chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
      colorList: colorList,
      initialAngleInDegree: 0,
      chartType: ChartType.ring,
      ringStrokeWidth: 32,
      centerText: "HYBRID",
      legendOptions: LegendOptions(
        showLegendsInRow: false,
        legendPosition: LegendPosition.right,
        showLegends: true,
        legendShape: _BoxShape.circle,
        legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      chartValuesOptions: ChartValuesOptions(
        showChartValueBackground: true,
        showChartValues: true,
        showChartValuesInPercentage: false,
        showChartValuesOutside: false,
        decimalPlaces: 1,
      ),
      // gradientList: ---To add gradient colors---
      // emptyColorGradient: ---Empty Color gradient---
    )
```

Comment: :) Happy coding 

Answer (score 0):

Got example from: [Donut Pie Chart Example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/donut)

```
// Donut chart example. This is a simple pie chart with a hole in the middle.    


import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DonutPieChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  DonutPieChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [PieChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory DonutPieChart.withSampleData() {
    return new DonutPieChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        // Configure the width of the pie slices to 60px. The remaining space in
        // the chart will be left as a hole in the center.
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcWidth: 60));
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 100),
      new LinearSales(1, 75),
      new LinearSales(2, 25),
      new LinearSales(3, 5),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```